# How can I center the the flyout items of a Xamarin Shell application?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, custom-renderer

I’d like to customize the look of the flyout of my Xamarin Shell application to vertically center its items. The [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout) shows how to customize some aspects of the flyout itself, but these settings can’t manipulate its look so that I can rearrange how the items are displayed.

[image]

Without a flyout header, the items are stacked on top of the flyout, but I need to center them vertically in the middle of the flyout itself.

My `ShellItemRenderer.cs` is currently empty because I don’t understand what I need to do. I currently have these classes:

```
internal class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer {
   public CustomShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

   protected override IShellTabLayoutAppearanceTracker CreateTabLayoutAppearanceTracker(ShellSection shellSection) {
      return new TabLayoutAppearanceTracker(this);                
   }

   protected override IShellItemRenderer CreateShellItemRenderer(ShellItem shellItem) {
      return new CustomShellItemRenderer(this);
   }
}

public class CustomShellItemRenderer :ShellItemRenderer {
   public CustomShellItemRenderer(IShellContext shellContext) : base(shellContext) { }
}
```

As you can see they are empty since I can’t figure out the needed modifications to make.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Shell.ItemTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#define-flyoutitem-appearance) to customize the flyout items:

```
<Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                   Margin="5"
                   HeightRequest="45" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding Title}"
                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center" /> 
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.ItemTemplate>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

You can also use [Shell.MenuItemTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#define-menuitem-appearance) to customize the MenuItem appearance.

Comment: This method is for styling the items: I need to customize the flyout itself.

Comment: What do you mean  `customize the flyout itself`? Can you please to add a picture to make it clear? You can customize the flyout in the ItemTemplate and add element there which you want.

Comment: @Pine Code wants to center the flyout items vertically, not horizontally: "I need to center them vertically in the middle of the flyout itself."

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yes, vertically.